# CRC-16 checksum is not matching for HDLC frames

Tags: protocols, crc, crc16, data-link-layer

I've a streaming HDLC data as follows:

```
 00 CE DB B1 FB 94 BC 51 D8 87 CF FF FB FF FF FF FB FF FF F9 7E AE 79 3D C4 D6 7B DB BD 7E 7B DF B8 FE 7B D8 7A 0B 3D ED DD 5B 3D EC DF 17 FF FC FE F3 FF FF FD 7F FC BD BF 9D BC 6C FF 05 FE FD FF 33 FE 51 FE C3 FE 43 FE 73 FE F1 FE 4A DF 36 FF A8 9F AB 9E 95 1E 4E 85 23 03 E6 EC 7E E5 2A 14 FF FE 5E 31 DE 0A 4F 88 4F EF 2F 96 1F 82 7F A7 FF 93 87 F2 BF F2 DF DE DF C2 DF C2 BF 9B 5F CE DF AA BF EB 3F F4 DF 84 DF D7 3F D1 5F E7 5F 98 DF DF 3F A1 5F 98 BF A7 3F ED 5F C8 DF B0 DF FC BF ED 7E 3B CB DC 49 34 A0
```

I want to decode the data and get the IP frames from its payload. From various resources regarding HDLC framing I've tracked out frame delimiters (0x7E) and get the HDLC frames as follows (2 of those frames):

## Frame-1

In the original order as it is received :

> **7E** AE 79 3D C4 D6 7B DB BD **7E**

In the reverse-byte order (as HDLC sends the least significant first):

> **7E** 75 9E BC 23 6B DE DB BD **7E**

## Frame-2

Original order:

> **7E** E5 2A 14 FF FE 5E 31 DE 0A 4F 88 4F EF 2F 96 1F 82 7F A7 FF 93 87 F2 BF F2 DF DE DF C2 DF C2 BF 9B 5F CE DF AA BF EB 3F F4 DF 84 DF D7 3F D1 5F E7 5F 98 DF DF 3F A1 5F 98 BF A7 3F ED 5F C8 DF B0 DF FC BF ED **7E**

Reverse-byte order:

> **7E** A7 54 28 FF 7F 7A 8C 7B 50 F2 11 F2 F7 F4 69 F8 41 FE E5 FF C9 E1 4F FD 4F FB 7B FB 43 FB 43 FD D9 FA 73 FB 55 FD D7 FC 2F FB 21 FB EB FC 8B FA E7 FA 19 FB FB FC 85 FA 19 FD E5 FC B7 FA 13 FB 0D FB 3F FD B7 **7E**

But the problem is, the last 2 byte CRC (**DB BD** for Frame-1 and **BF ED** for Frame-2) is not matching for any of the frames.

I've tried suggestions from many forums, of which these 2 were most relevant:

https://www.lammertbies.nl/forum/viewtopic.php?t=607

[Calculating FCS(CRC) for HDLC frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983862/calculating-fcscrc-for-hdlc-frame)

Please help.

Comment: You might not be extracting the HDLC data correctly.

Comment: Yes I too suspect that. But from various HDLC documents this is what I figured (extracting the frame between 0x7E flags).

This is the raw data I received :

00 CE DB B1 FB 94 BC 51 D8 87 CF FF FB FF FF FF FB FF FF F9 7E AE 79 3D C4 D6 7B DB BD 7E 7B DF B8

Is there any other way ?